# Sort array with Int

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, sorting

I want to sort my array with the highest timestamp to the lowest timestamp. First I want to fetch all data from Firebase and add this in the array, when all data is fetched I want to sort the array. When I try to do this, I will get this error on line `posts.sort(by: {$0.timestamp > $1.timestamp})` :

> Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands

This is my code:

```
var posts: [Post] = []

Api.MyPosts.fetchMyPosts(userId: self.userId) { (key) in
     Api.Post.observePost(withId: key, completion: {
         post in
         self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
         self.tableView.reloadData()
      })        
      posts.sort(by: {$0.timestamp > $1.timestamp})       
 }
```

Does anybody knows how I can fix this error and keep timestamp as a int?

Comment: `posts.sort(by: {$0.timestamp ?? 0 > $1.timestamp ?? 0})`

Comment: A few things. The question asks about Firebase but there's no Firebase code shown. Secondly, we don't know how your Post class is defined. Also, that code doesn't appear to read posts, it looks like it only reads one. Lastly - and this is the important one. Do you want to sort the data in code or do you want Firebase to present the data descending? There are a LOT of solutions here on SO in regards to that specific topic.

Comment: Your int var appears to be an optional. If it's guaranteed to always have a value define it like this `var int = 0` or like this `var num: Int!` which will also take care of that error. If it's populated from Firebase then do this `let timestamp = firebase_stuff.value as? Int ?? 0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `unwrap` the `timestamp` since it is an `optional Int` value, i.e.

```
posts.sort {
    guard let t1 = $0, let t2 = $1 else {
        return false
    }
    return t1 > t2
}
```

Comment: That is not a good suggestion, the behavior would be undefined. The predicate is not a “strict weak ordering,” as required by the sort method. The “transitive incomparability”  condition is violated. (And there is a typo: the second `$0` should probably be `$1`.)